# How to export my favorite questions on stack-exchange as pdf?

Tags: support, export

Is there a way to export my favorite questions merged as pdf? If there is no such thing why don't you think about it?

Comment: [First](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf) and [second](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/is-it-possible-to-convert-and-possibly-download-the-answers-discussions-in-pdf).